# Setting extra variables to a buttonclicklistener in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener, simpleadapter

in my app i have a listview(asynctask) getting all the users from external database. Each row of my listview contains an image that the user can interact. When user presses that image i try to start a new intent by using the data that i already have(by using putExtra while starting the intent.) Listview works fine - it gathers all the data from database. But, the putExtra values are same for each row. I will appreciate if you can help me regarding that matter.

Code is as follows;
The important part is below

`ImageView showlastonmap = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.showlastonmap);`

where i try to add putExtra.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {

            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                //Invitation count

                Integer inv =  json.getInt("invitation");
                setNotifCount(inv);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {

                    // Getting JSON Array from URL

                    android1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATIONDATA);
                    for (int i = 0; i < android1.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = android1.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                        final String ver = c.getString("username"); 
                        final String dataenlem = c.getString("enlem");
                        final String databoylam = c.getString("boylam");
                        final String datazaman = c.getString("zaman");

                        /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                        StringBuffer address = new StringBuffer();
                        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        List<Address> addresses;
                        try {
                            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(dataenlem), Double.parseDouble(databoylam), 1);

                            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                               // System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                                address.append(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1))
                                        .append(",").append(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String datalokasyon = address.toString();
                        /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */

                        // Adding value HashMap key => value
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                        map.put("enlem", dataenlem);
                        map.put("boylam", databoylam);
                        map.put("zaman", datazaman);
                        map.put("lokasyon", datalokasyon);


                        oslist.add(map);

                        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                        BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserList.this, oslist,
                                R.layout.listview_userlist,
                                new String[]{TAG_VER,"zaman","lokasyon"}, new int[]{
                                R.id.vers,R.id.lastlocationinput,R.id.lastupdatedinput}) {

                            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                            {

                                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                                ImageView showlastonmap = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.showlastonmap);

                                showlastonmap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(View v) {



                                        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                                HaritaLastSolo.class);
                                        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        login.putExtra("enlem", dataenlem);
                                        login.putExtra("boylam", databoylam);
                                        startActivity(login);

                                    }
                                });
                                return v;
                            }

                        };

                       SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
                        animationAdapter.setAbsListView(list);

                        list.setAdapter(animationAdapter);
       }

                    //admob
                    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        public void onAdLoaded() {
                            displayInterstitial();
                        }
                    });
                    //admob


                }
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 0) {

                    new SweetAlertDialog(UserList.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("Oops...")
                            .setContentText(getString(R.string.userlist_nofriend))
                            .show();
                }

            }

            else {

                return;
            }
             }catch
             (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do :

```
 Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
           HaritaLastSolo.class);
         login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           login.putExtra("enlem", oslist.get(position).get("enlem"));
           login.putExtra("boylam", oslist.get(position).get("boylam"));
          startActivity(login);
```

Comment: wow. works like a charm :) I wish I had asked it earlier, i have spent 5 hours to find a solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new object which contains required fields.

```
class Data { 
    String dataenlem;
    String databoylam;
    Data(String dataenlem, String databoylam) {
     ...
    }
}
```

and then set corresponding to each row data using setTag method

```
 ImageView showlastonmap = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.showlastonmap);
  // add this
 showlastonmap.setTag(new Data(dataenlem, databoylam));
```

and get it on your onClick

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   // and this
   Data data = (Data)v.getTag();

   Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HaritaLastSolo.class);
   login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   login.putExtra("enlem", data.dataenlem);
   login.putExtra("boylam", data.databoylam);
   startActivity(login);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have tried but did not work.